# How can I put colon in a abstract and justify it?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, abstract

I need something like this (with colon, justify it and capital letter):

```
ABSTRACT:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now I just have something like this:

```
                        Abstract
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `abstract` environment is mere a `quotation` environment with a heading. So, the following is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
\noindent ABSTRACT:\ \lipsum[1]
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks, but the abstract is not aligned with the rest of the text, it is a little to the right, can I fix it?

Comment: @damb: Yes, that's due to the `quotation` environment. If you wish to avoid that, just use `\noindent ABSTRACT:\ ...`. You don't mention anything about formatting the word `ABSTRACT`. But that can also be done.